# how to install windows 8 on Mac mini (late 2012) with Mac Mavericks on it

Tags: windows-8, mac

I'm using macmini late 2012 with Mac OSX 10.9.1 on it. My machine has not CD/DVD drive and I tried to install windows 8.1 pro via USB (using BootCamp to push image file to USB). But I can't boot from USB (I hold option key when booting system).
what should i do?

Comment: According to Apple KB here > http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634, you can install windows 8 (64bit) with boot camp. Have you created a partition to install windows using boot camp & a bootable USB drive.? what does it say when you try to boot?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment as my reputation level won't let me. However, I'm having similar issues with installing Win 8.1 onto my late 2012 Mac Mini.

Are you able to get to the boot source options? If so, try unplugging all of the other USB devices. If not, try with a USB keyboard, I've heard from references that it may be an issue as well.

Then try following the steps in the source, I have not been able to finish all of the steps, but I was able to get the furthest using the following guide.

Source: http://www.royhochstenbach.com/installing-windows-8-1-on-a-2013-mac-pro/

Answer (score -1):

The thing is, there are different partition tables to use, and in order to boot Apple operative systems (like Mac), the partition table has to be GUID (or GPT). If you want to boot a Microsoft operative systems (like Windows) you would have to change the partition table into MBR.

You could do that with the software/app called *Disk Utility* on Mac by formatting it (don't forget to change the partition table in *Advanced Settings*). I'm sorry but I don't know what the equivalence of Windows would be.

Comment: This is wrong. Windows as of 7 supports GUID and 8 actually PREFERS to be installed on a GUID partition if there is a UEFI bios (all Intel Mac's have UEFI).